# Duplicating Files in same folder

Tags: powershell

Hello Powershell Noob here, I am trying to write a script that will take paths from my clipboard and just duplicate them right in their parent folder.

Lets say my clipboard looks like this:

```
"C:\Users\User1\New Folder\Image A.jpg"
"C:\Users\User1\New Folder\Image B.jpg"
"C:\Users\User1\New Folder\Image C.jpg"
```

I know its just a matter of `Copy-Item`  but I am stuck on correctly appending "`(1)`" on the file name each file name. I've tried:

```
$objectList = Get-Clipboard
Foreach($Object in $ObjectList){
$i
$NewName = Join-Path -Path $Object -ChildPath ((Split-Path $Object -Leaf) + $i)
Copy-Item -Path $Object -Destination $NewName}
```

Sometimes I get a result like:

```
"C:\Users\User1\New Folder\Image A.jpg1"
```

but I mostly just end up getting red errors, I've read the docs and trawled stack overflow and I've gotton even more confused.

Can anyone help me understand how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You should  make the objects proper file system objects using `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem`. This way you can access their individual elements like `BaseName` and `Extension` to be able to rename only the `BaseName`.  ;-) And BTW: You did not define `$i`! ;-)

Comment: And BTW: it would have been nice if you at least declared that you crossposted the same question to another forum [Is it OK to cross-post a question between non-Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159)  .... [Powershell- Duplicating Files in same folder Please!](https://forums.powershell.org/t/powershell-duplicating-files-in-same-folder-please/19271)

Comment: You... asked the exact same question on Reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/ulxyje/powershell_duplicating_files_in_same_folder_please/

Comment: @Olaf A few months ago this was one of the selling points of powershell I kept running into what its "Object based" approach, I even appreciated this in an earlier example you helped me with on the other Powershell forum.  I completely forgot about this object feature this time around!! This is a painfull realisation for me, I thank you bringing it to my attention!

Comment: As for the Cross site posting, perhaps it was and is in bad etique to do this. Going forward I will mention in posts that I have taken the liberty to ask this same question in other places. The reason why I do it is that I am new to programming and I am not only intrested in solving the one issue but being exposed to conventions/approaches  through varrying examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$objectList = Get-Clipboard
Foreach ($Object in $ObjectList) {
    $File = Get-Item -Path $Object
    $NewName = Join-Path -Path $File.Directory -ChildPath ($File.BaseName + '1' + $File.Extension)
    Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $NewName
}
```

Comment: this worked great, I spent about 4 hours trying to get at this yesterday but you expressed succinctly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you so much!